# Able to use submit button for selecting top choice

Tags: algolia

I'm wondering how I can implement a submit button that works like `autoselect: true` so when I click submit, it selects the first suggestion.

Here is the scenario, I've started typing and then I want the user to be able to click the submit button to confirm what is 0934.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sebastian, did you resolve your issue? Any update?

Answer (score 2):

The [PR #101](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/pull/101) has just been merged and released in the `0.21.4` version. With this new feature, the cursor will automatically be set on the first suggestion when `autoselect: true`.

You can then remember the latest selected suggestion and use it while submitting the form:

```
$('#contacts').autocomplete({ hint: false, autoselect: true }, [
  {
    source: autocomplete.sources.hits(indexObj, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
    displayKey: 'name',
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion._highlightResult.name.value;
      }
    }
  }
]).on('autocomplete:cursorchanged autocomplete:selected', function(e, sugg) {
  console.log('last', sugg);
  lastSelectedEntry = sugg;
});

$('#form').on('submit', function() {
  alert(lastSelectedEntry);
});
```

I've done a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/sylvainutard/pen/zKYELA).